# pandas dataframe reshape cast

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame([['a','b'],['a','c'],['b','c'],['b','d'],['c','f']],columns=['id','key'])
print(df)

  id key
0  a   b
1  a   c
2  b   c
3  b   d
4  c   f
```

the result that I wanted：

```
   id  key
0  a  b,c
1  b  c,d
2  c    f
```

I try use pivot function, but I don't get the result. The cast packages in R seems to tackle the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` `join`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('id')['key'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
print (df1)
  id  key
0  a  b,c
1  b  c,d
2  c    f
```

Answer (score 3):

***a `numpy` approach***

```
g = df.id.values
k = df.key.values
a = g.argsort(kind='mergesort')
gg = g[a]
kg = k[a]

w = np.where(gg[:-1] != gg[1:])[0]

pd.DataFrame(dict(
        id=gg[np.append(w, len(a) - 1)],
        key=[','.join(l.tolist()) for l in np.split(kg, w + 1)]
    ))

  id  key
0  a  b,c
1  b  c,d
2  c    f
```

---

***speed versus intuition***

[image]